# Snubber capacitor Voltage rating

Tags: capacitance, emc, inductive, tvs, snubber

I am designing a switching circuit for celing fan (max 80W/230VAC). This is basically relay based switching. 
I planned to add snubber circuit to reduce the back emf.
I got a resistor value of 100Ω and 0.1µF capacitance when I did a google search.

1. I have a film capacitor of 1KV DC voltage rating and second one 440AC X2 class rated. Which one will be more suitable?
2. If I want to add TVS to cap the max voltage, what voltage rating will give the beat results?

Comment: Ceiling fans use switched film capacitor impedance to change speed. What are you doing?

Comment: I am trying ro automate it using relays. Basically on /Off

Comment: Snubbing and speed control require a schematic with specs and are two different issues

Comment: Here basically an inductive load(ceiling fan) ON/OFf through a Relay. I will attach the sch soon